# What is the smallest possible Windows shellcode?

Tags: web-browser, threat-modeling, security-theater

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there any tools that focus on shellcode analysis?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18958/are-there-any-tools-that-focus-on-shellcode-analysis)

Any tools available that is for shellcode analysis? what methods are used in reverse engineering?

Comment: It depends what windows and what it aims to bypass to avoid detection.

Comment: The smallest possible is `0x90` - a NOP instruction. It does absolutely nothing.